# How to loop through column of data and search all worksheets for current value?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a sheet called IDs that has a list of ids in column A. I want to loop through that column and for each value, search all sheets for that value and output the location to a new sheet. Currently right now I am looping through values and sheets, but having some trouble.

```
Sub Find()

Dim I As Long, temp As String
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim A As Integer

WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For I = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    temp = Cells(I, "A").Value
    For A = 1 To WS_Count
         ' Search current value in sheets.
    Next A
Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: "having some trouble." what troubles, exactly? Do you need VBA for this, sounds like this could be done with `MATCH`

Comment: I am creating a macro in VBA to search through value in a column and having trouble with implimenting the .find method to search each sheet for the current value the for loop is at

Comment: "trouble" doesn't tell us anything about the specific problem you're having with your code.  What does it do or not do which is different from what you want?  Plenty of previous questions on this topic: https://www.google.com/search?q=Excel+vba+search+across+worksheets+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

What I have done is create a sub that searches for similar IDs in other sheets. I have tested this by adding a bit of code which can be replaced with whatever you intend to do with the matched IDs.

```
Sub Find()

Dim findVal As String, IDLocation As String
Dim IDSheet As Worksheet
    Set IDSheet = Worksheets("IDSheet")
Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    k = 1

'loop through each cell in the first column and store its value in the "findVal" 
variable
N = IDSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To N
    findVal = Cells(i, 1).Value
    j = 2
    'Loop each sheet in the workbook
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    
        'Do not search through IDSheet
        If ws.Name = IDSheet.Name Then
        'do nothing
        Else
    
        'Loop each cell in the sheet for the "findVal" variable
        For Each c In ws.UsedRange
            If c.Value = findVal Then
                'Stores the location of the like ID
                IDLocation = ws.Name & ": (" & c.Row & ", " & c.Column & ")"
                IDSheet.Cells(k, j) = IDLocation
                j = j + 1
            Else
            'Do nothing
            End If
        Next
        End If
    Next
    k = k + 1
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more of the output? I tried running it and don't see anything happening.

Comment: The above code reads the value of A2 on worksheet IDSheet, and then scans all other worksheets for any cell that holds the same value. If it is found, it outputs the location to the adjacent cell B2. If it finds more than one, it writes them to C2, D2.. etc. Then it moves to A3 and starts again, looping until the cell in column A it reads next is blank.

Comment: If it's working but not outputting any locations, then maybe the code needs to be tweaked to a `Like` statement to find cells that *contain* the `findVal` rather than cells that *equal* the `findVal`.? e.g. `If c.Value Like "*" & findVal & "*" Then`

Comment: I was also unsure of what you wanted the code to do once you found the like ID, so I improvised something to do with it. CLR explained what it does well. It outputs each instance of the ID not on the IDSheet in a row after the ID. One reason why it may not be working for you is that the sheet containing the IDs must be named "IDSheet" or you could modify the {Set IDSheet = Worsksheets("IDSheet")} to be a different sheet name.